# Resize text based on div resizing?

Tags: html, css, fonts, resize

To start things off, here is my code:

```
.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #FF4545;

}
.headertext{
    font-family: 'Duru Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 65px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.headermenu{
    font-family: 'Duru Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 65px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
```

So both the .headertext and the .headermenu are html p statements that are embedded within the .header div. Now, the .header div has a bg color. When I resize my window, the div resizes (very clearly with the bg color) however the text does not resize. It makes sense that the text doesn't resize given that I have assigned a concrete font size for them. I wanted to ask how I can have the font size dynamically scale so that the text is always kept within the div? At this point it pokes out the bottom when you resize, meaning half the text is within the bg colored div and half of it is sticking out into whitespace. I hope this is clear enough, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use change it like this:

1) Add  "font-size: 65px;" to the class ".header"
2) Replace the definition of font-size in the class ".headertext" and ".headermenu" by "font-size: 1em;"

Thus, the child will get the same size of the parent node. Therefore, when the parent is resized, the children nodes will be resized too.

Answer (score 0):

Defining your font size in pixels makes them definite sizes instead of something that will scale well with a fluid layout. Define your fonts in em instead of pixels. To find the proper em size you divide the font size by 16 which is the standard font size for browsers. For instance, your font size of 65 pixels would become 4.0625em (65 / 16 = 4.0625).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no CSS way to make `font-size` smoothly scale on window resize.

You might try CSS Media Query too set `font-size` relative to specific widths/heights

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ww4hB/

Otherwise, you need JavaScript to update font size on page load and window resize.

**edit:**

There is also something called `viewport unit`, but it isn't supported in all browsers.

See more: http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/